# How to set chef environment attribute from a recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I want to set an attribute in the environment itself so that any node in the environment can use it.

Like:
node.set['install_wls']['adminserver'] = "#{node[:ipaddress]}"

I am not able to find how to do it from a recipe?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this, at least not by default and the changes in ACLs required for it would be a major security problem so you very much shouldn't. Normally you would use Chef Search (i.e. `search(:nodes, "roles:adminserver").first["ipaddress"]`) for this, though Chef Search is a pretty minimalist service discovery tool and something like Consul is far more flexible and has more useful features.